# How to call a method in another class from a generic method?

Tags: c#

Why doesn't the line marked with `//Dont work in the bottom of the code` compile?

I want to reuse the `WriteMessage` method with different Classes, I try to use `generics`, but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
class ClassOne
{
    public string MethodOne()
    {
        return ("ClassOne");
    }

    public string MethodTwo()
    {
        return ("ClassOne -MethodTwo ");
    }
}

class ClassTwo 
{
    public string MethodOne()
    {
        return ("ClassTwo");
    }

    public string MethodTwo()
    {
        return ("ClassOne -MethodTwo ");
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var objectOne = new ClassOne();
        WriteMessage(objectOne);

        var objectTwo = new ClassTwo();
        WriteMessage(objectTwo);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void WriteMessage<T>(T objectA)
    {
        var text = objectA.MethodTwo();  //Dont Work
        Console.WriteLine("Text:{0}", text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try implementing a interface :

Example :

```
public interface IHasTwoMethods
{
 string MethodOne()
 string MethodTwo()
}
```

Implement this inteface on your classes :

```
class ClassOne : IHasTwoMethods
class ClassTwo : IHasTwoMethods
```

Then in your generic method do like this :

```
public static void WriteMessage<T>(T objectA) where T : IHasTwoMethods
    {
        var text = objectA.MethodTwo();  //Will work
        Console.WriteLine("Text:{0}", text);
    }
```

You can read more about interfaces here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx

Comment: +1 The more important concept here is a generic type constraint (not the interface) but the solution is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't compile because as far as the compiler is concerned `objectA` is just an `Object`.

To get this to work, you need to use a **generic type constraint**:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
   string MethodTwo();
}

public class A : MyInterface
{
   ...
}

public class B : MyInterface
{
   ...
}

public static void WriteMessage<T>(T objectA) where T: MyInterface
{
    var text = objectA.MethodTwo();  //Will Work!
    Console.WriteLine("Text:{0}", text);
}
```

MSDN : [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: @elgonzo Yep, I think I've mis-typed that at least 3 or 4 times writing this post :(

Comment: Don't worry, i had quite the fun saying out loud "Method2 is not the same as MethodTwo" ;)

Comment: @elgonzo I'll bet. Now I understand why everyone names their functions "foo" and "bar" :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're passing in a generically-typed object with `T`, the compiler doesn't know what class you're using--for all it knows, it could be an `int` or an `Application` or anything.

What you probably want is to have `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` inherit from another class that has an abstract `MethodTwo` class that both implement. Something like...

```
abstract class SuperClass
{
    public abstract string MethodOne();
}

class ClassOne : SuperClass
{
    public override string MethodOne()
    {
        return ("ClassOne");
    }
}
```

then in Main:

```
public static void WriteMessage<T>(T objectA) where T : SuperClass
{
    var text = objectA.MethodOne();
    Console.WriteLine("Text:{0}", text);
}
```

Read up on C# inheritance here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

Comment: Technically this wouldn't work, since you have `MethodOne` as the method in the abstract class, but call `MethodTwo`.

Comment: Sloppy copy-paste on my part.